# display the imageview after listview

Tags: android

i want to add the imageview after listview. In listview i have so many elements.so my xml file is like this please look and help me what i want to add in this xml file..


    
        
            
            
        
          -->

```
        <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/search_layout"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal">
            <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/autocomplete_country"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="Search"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"> -->
        <ListView android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/search_layout"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/orbit"
            android:layout_below="@+id/listview"

            />
         <!-- </ScrollView> -->

    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- </ScrollView> -->
    <!-- <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"> -->

    <!-- </RelativeLayout> -->
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

add attribute `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in your ImageView and add this in your ListView    `android:layout_above="@+id/imageViewId"`

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked for me except adding the ImageView as `Footer` of ListView.

Better put your ImageView in a separate layout file and then inflate it programmatically and add it to the list as a footer view.

```
View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_image_view, null);
listView.addFooterView(footer);
```